# C++ Templates - The Complete Guide: Understanding footnote comment about decltype and return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, decltype, void-t

The 2nd edition of *C++ Templates - The Complete Guide* features the following code at page 435

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct HasBeginT : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct HasBeginT<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().begin())>>
    : std::true_type {};
```

and comments that `decltype(std::declval<T>().begin())` is used to test whether it is valid to call `.begin()` on a `T`.

This all makes sense, I think...

What staggers me is the comment in the footnote:

> Except that `decltype(call-expression)` does not require a nonreference, non-`void` return type to be complete, unlike call expressions in other contexts. Using `decltype(std::declval<T>().begin(), 0)` instead does add the requirement that the return type of the call is complete, because the returned value is no longer the result of the `decltype` operand.

I don't really understand it.

In an attempt to play with it, I tried to see what it behaves with a `void` member `begin`, with the following code

```cpp
struct A {
    void begin() const;
};

struct B {
};

static_assert(HasBeginT<A>::value, "");
static_assert(!HasBeginT<B>::value, "");
```

but both assertions pass with or without the `, 0`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your demo uses `void begin() const;` to test the following

> ... instead does add the requirement that the return type of the call is *complete* ...

But a `void` return type is not the same as an incomplete return type. For that you could try

```
struct X;

struct A {
    X begin() const;
};
```

Here, `X` is indeed incomplete, and now the `, 0` matters. With it, the first `static_assert` won't pass, but it passes without the `, 0`.

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bojceWPjx)

Comment: ... because the comma may be overloaded.

Comment: Yeah, the answer truly tells how I misread/misunderstood the text. But know that I know how I should read it, I still don't understand how it works. Why does the comme have that effect?

Comment: @Enlico Actually, I'm not sure why it has that effect. StoryTeller's comment seems to hint at that, but I'm not sure I get why. I'll see if I can work it out. You  *could* edit the question to ask *why*, but that should probably be a different question.

Comment: @cigien in the case no worries and stay tuned, I'll ask another question

Comment: @Enlico cppreference [says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) "The type need not be complete or have an available destructor, and can be abstract. **This rule doesn't apply to sub-expressions**: in `decltype(f(g()))`, `g()` must have a complete type, but `f()` need not." So it's not just comma, but any subexpression. I still don't know *why* the rule exists.

Comment: @Enlico Ok, I think I worked it out from [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3233.html), it's in the solution section. Basically, `decltype(f(g())` or `decltype(f(), 0)` for that matter, might need to do overload resolution, which requires conversions, and that requires type completeness. I get what StoryTeller meant now; as usual they're several steps ahead of me :)

Comment: Oh, so the `, 0` is "only" a mean to trigger overload resolution (_because the comma may be overloaded_) which, in turn, requires the type-completeness of the return type of `f()`. I could as well define `auto f = [](auto const&){};` and then do `decltype(f(std::declval<T>().begin()))` to have the same behavior, right?

Comment: @Enlico Yes, that appears to be correct https://godbolt.org/z/x4jMeoj63

Comment: @cigien, I've asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352671/c-templates-the-complete-guide-wording-of-footnote-about-decltype-and-retur) nonetheless, because there's still something unclear for me.