# C++ Templates - The Complete Guide: Wording of footnote about decltype and return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, decltype, comma-operator

The 2nd edition of *C++ Templates - The Complete Guide* features the following footnote at page 436 (my **bold**):

> Except that `decltype(call-expression)` does not require a nonreference, non-`void` return type to be complete, unlike call expressions in other contexts. Using `decltype(std::declval<T>().begin(), 0)` instead does add the requirement that the return type of the call is complete, **because the returned value is no longer the result of the `decltype` operand**.

The footnote refers to the fact that `decltype(std::declval<T>().begin())` is used (ineffectively, based on the footnote) to test whether it is valid to call `.begin()` on a `T`. The code that uses it is the following (with some pieces of text around it for clarity:

> the trick is to formulate the expression that checks whether we can call `begin()` inside a `decltype` expression for the default value of an additional function template parameter:
>
> ```cpp
> #include <utility>      // for declval
> #include <type_traits>  // for true_type, false_type, and void_t
> // primary template:
> template<typename, typename = std::void_t<>>
> struct HasBeginT : std::false_type {};
> // partial specialization (may be SFINAE’d away):
> template<typename T>
> struct HasBeginT<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().begin())>>
>   : std::true_type {
> };
> ```
>
> Here, we use `decltype(std::declval<T>().begin())` to test whether, given a value/object of type `T` (using `std::declval` to avoid any constructor being required), calling a member `begin()` is valid.

From [this previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69350834/c-templates-the-complete-guide-understanding-footnote-comment-about-decltyp), I've understood that since `operator,` can be overloaded, the role of the `, 0` is to trigger the otherwise absent overload resolution, which in turn needs the type of `std::declval<T>().begin()` to be complete.

However, the text from the book (see the part highlighted in **bold** above), doesn't mention `operator,`, nor overload resolution. Is that just bad wording? Or maybe it's just the same matter looked from a different perspective? Or what?

Comment: `begin()` implies an iterator being returned, and iterators have a fairly familiar expected API, such that for that example it vaguely reasonable to assume there won't be an overloaded comma operator.  In the general case though, your point is reasonable.

Comment: My frame of mind when commenting on cigien's answer is explained by HolyBlackCat. But I will amend it. The type doesn't have to be complete just because of overloading. Obviously, for a function call (such as an overload) the argument must be complete (initialization and deinitialization is part of the call). But even in the absence of overloads, the comma operator evaluates and discards the lhs. For a class prvalue, this involves materializing a temporary, so we again do initializiation and deinitializiation and require a complete type.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the original source material is talking about, but I cannot be sure, because you only included a footnote and I do not know what it was it was talking about.  "it is value to call `begin()` on a `T`" is fuzzy in meaning in C++, there are multiple reasonable ways to map the word "is valid" in English to different concepts in C++.  I don't know where the decltype is, I don't know what the goal is.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, have I added enough information?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the author forgot or disregarded the possibility of `,` being overloaded. The whole technique is defective in this regard, not just the wording.

So if `begin()` is valid and returns a complete type, but `,` is overloaded and can't be called for some reason, you'll get a false negative.

A more robust solution would be `decltype(void(std::declval<T>().begin()))`.

Comment: If I'm correct in saying that (in this case) `void(std::declval<T>().begin())` is the same as `(void)std::declval<T>().begin()` and it means you're converting the result of `.begin()` to `void`... how does this work? Why does it have the effect of enforcing that requirement?

Comment: @Enlico You're not asking the question properly IMO. Your question focuses on the wording in the book, whereas based on all your comments, you should be asking about the behavior of decltype with sub-expressions involving incomplete types.

Comment: @cigien that's another shade of the question. But for now I don't know how to ask it. I would essentially link the page you linked and ask _explain this to me_.

Comment: @Enlico Fair enough. I'll see if I can formulate that question myself, and post one if I can.